# get values from dynamically created combobox for postbackurl

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, devexpress

here's the thing, I'm a not experienced programmer and I'm creating a web store from scratch, I can list all products and and I dynamically created a button on each product to add it to cart, then I Added a combobox for product quantity, and here's the problem.

before I was sending product ID on URL, but now I can't find a way to send the product quantity, because before I was creating the URL with postbackURL and adding the product ID into the URL, that was OK.

so now, I need a way to add the quantity to URL, I don't know how to do this with dynamically created controls, I created an ID for each button and combobox + a number that is randomly generated(both button and combobox has the same number, so I know the name of each).

btw I'm using devexpress framework.

here's my code that is inserted into a container:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.DynamicData;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using DevExpress.Web;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using WebArrendatariosDX.Class;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WebArrendatariosDX.Productos
{
    public partial class ProductMaster : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetProducts();
        }

        private void GetProducts()
        {
            var icc = (string) Session["icc"];
            var cid = (string) Session["uid"];
            var dbc = new DbClass();
            dbc.GetConnStr("dbtoconnect");
            string str;
            dbc.SetQueryType("TXT", out str);
            dbc.SetQuery("SP_GET_PRODUCTS @CUSTOMER_ID=" + cid + ", @CLIENT_ID=" + icc, out str);
            SqlDataReader rdr = dbc.exec_ret_sqldatareader();
            try
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    //<Tabla de producto>
                    var productTable = new Table {CssClass = "templateTable"}; //<table></table>
                    productTable.Attributes.Add("RUNAT","SERVER");
                    productTable.Rows.Add(maketitleRow(rdr["ST_DESC_TIPOPRODUCTO"].ToString(), rdr["ID"].ToString(),
                        rdr["ST_CODINTERNO_TIPOPRODUCTO"].ToString()));
                    //<tr></tr>
                    productTable.Rows.Add(makecontentRow(rdr["ST_DESC_MARCAPRODUCTO"].ToString(),
                        rdr["IN_PRECIOVENTA_TIPOPRODUCTO"].ToString(), 1)); //<tr></tr>
                    productTable.Rows.Add(makecontentRow(rdr["ST_DESC_MARCAPRODUCTO"].ToString(),
                        rdr["IN_PRECIOVENTA_TIPOPRODUCTO"].ToString(), 2)); //<tr></tr>

                    //</Tabla de producto>
                    products_container.Controls.Add(productTable); //meter contenido a la tabla
                    products_container.Controls.Add(new Literal() {Text = "<br />"});
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var errorTable = new Table {CssClass = "templateTable"}; //<table></table>
                var errorRow = new TableRow(); //<tr></tr>
                var errorCell = new TableCell
                {
                    Text = "Error al consultar productos: " + ex.Message + "<br> Intente recargando la pagina.",
                    ColumnSpan = 4,
                    CssClass = "value"
                }; //<td></td>
                errorRow.Cells.Add(errorCell);
                errorTable.Rows.Add(errorRow);
                products_container.Controls.Add(errorTable);
            }

        }

        private string tob64(string toconv)
        {
            byte[] bytesToEncode = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toconv);
            string encodedText = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesToEncode);
            return encodedText;
        }

        private TableRow maketitleRow(string productName, string imgid, string sku)
        {
            var titleRow = new TableRow(); //<tr></tr>
            var titleImageCell = new TableCell { CssClass = "imageCell", RowSpan = 3 };
            var ime = new ASPxImage {Width = 120, Height = 120};
            ime.ImageUrl = "~/Util/image.ashx?id=" + imgid;
            titleImageCell.Controls.Add(ime);
            var titleCell = new TableCell {Text = productName, ColumnSpan = 3, CssClass = "value"}; //<td></td>
            //**** COLUMNA CON BOTONES
            var ButtonsCell = new TableCell { CssClass = "imageCell", RowSpan = 3 };
            var btn_addtoCart = new ASPxButton();
            var cbx_qty = new ASPxComboBox(); //the combobox that I need to get the value from
            cbx_qty.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.DropDownList;
            cbx_qty.Items.Add("Cantidad...", 0);
            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
            {
                cbx_qty.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(i), i);
            }
            cbx_qty.SelectedIndex = 0;
            btn_addtoCart.Text = "Agregar al Carro";
            var rnd = new Random();
            int rnds = rnd.Next(6236, 6124125);
            btn_addtoCart.ID = "btn_atc_" + rnds; //my button that is created dynamically with a custom name
            string idbtn = btn_addtoCart.ID.ToString();
            cbx_qty.ID = "cbx_" + idbtn; //my custom ID for each combobox that is created dynamically
            btn_addtoCart.PostBackUrl = "~/Productos/Cart/CartMaster.aspx?nod=" + tob64(sku) + "&pid=" + rnds;// this works but now I need to add the quantity
            ButtonsCell.Controls.Add(cbx_qty);
            ButtonsCell.Controls.Add(btn_addtoCart);
            //**** /COLUMNA CON BOTONES
            titleRow.Cells.Add(titleImageCell); //IMAGEN DEL PRODUCTO
            titleRow.Cells.Add(titleCell); //TITULO DEL PRODUCTO
            titleRow.Cells.Add(ButtonsCell); //AGREGA BOTONES
            return titleRow;
        }

        private TableRow makecontentRow(string manufacturer, string price, int rowno)
        {
            var contentRow = new TableRow(); //<tr></tr>
            if (rowno == 1)
            {
                var contentManufacturerTextCell = new TableCell { Text = "Fabricante" }; //<td></td>
                var contentManufacturerCell = new TableCell { Text = manufacturer, CssClass = "value" }; //<td></td>
                contentRow.Cells.Add(contentManufacturerTextCell);
                contentRow.Cells.Add(contentManufacturerCell);
            }
            else if (rowno == 2)
            {
                var contentPriceTextCell = new TableCell { Text = "Precio" }; //<td></td>
                var contentPriceCell = new TableCell { Text = "$ " + price, CssClass = "value" }; //<td></td>
                contentRow.Cells.Add(contentPriceTextCell);
                contentRow.Cells.Add(contentPriceCell);
            }
            return contentRow;
        }
    }
}
```